# new Class item displaying as object instead of string

Tags: ruby

I'm still extremely new to Ruby. I took a class on Codecademy and I'm currently doing the "Final" where I have to make a todo list.

One of the parts of the todo list is to be able to add tasks (obviously). Another part is to be able to show all current tasks. Now, technically, both of these are working. But, when I create a new task using the class I made (Task) and then show the tasks, it displays the object ID instead of the string. If I simply use my add method without using my Task class, it will display the string like I want it too.

My goal is to get my script to display the string while using the Task class. If someone could please explain to me why it's not working and how I can fix it, I'd appreciate that.

Here's the code:

```
## Classes ##

#List Class - Used for anything involving the list
class List
  attr_reader :all_tasks

  def initialize
    @all_tasks = []
  end

  def add(task)
    all_tasks << task
  end

  def show
    all_tasks
  end
end

#Task Class - Used for anything involving Tasks
class Task
  attr_reader :description

  def initialize(description)
    @description = description
  end
end

## Modules ##
module Promptable
  def prompt(message = "What would you like to do?", symbol = " >: ")
    print message
    print symbol
    gets.chomp
  end

  def show
    menu
  end
end


module Menu
  def menu
    puts "
    'add' - Add a task to the list \n
    'delete' - Delete a task from the list \n
    'update' - Update a task in the list \n
    'show' - Shows current tasks in list"
  end
end

#Methods - various methods


#Program Runner
if __FILE__ == $PROGRAM_NAME
  include Menu
  include Promptable

  my_list = List.new
  puts "Please choose from the following list: "
  until ['q'].include?(user_input = prompt(show).downcase)
    case user_input
    when 'add'
      puts "What task would you like to do?"
      my_list.add(Task.new(gets.chomp))
    when 'q'
      puts "Qutting...."
    when 'show'
      puts my_list.show
    else "That is not a valid command"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
puts my_list.show
```

Will display the tasks one by one. Since the `Task` class doesn't have a `to_s` method, the default one will be used. Just add one:

```
class Task
  # ...

  alias to_s description
end
```

BTW strings are objects too. Pretty much everything in Ruby is an object.

Comment: Good to know! Thank you so much!